# Why the European Eurofighter Typhoon did not have pitot tube in front of the radome?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, eurofighter-typhoon

The layout of the aircraft does not have the proper pitot tube. I believe that the aircraft needs clean airflow for its instruments .

Comment: To my knowledge, on most airliners the pitot tube is in line with the flight deck, well aft of the nose and radome. On smaller aircraft the pitot tube may be mounted on the wing. Why do you believe it should be placed at the very front of the aircraft?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are IAS to CAS conversions calculated?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/41030/how-are-ias-to-cas-conversions-calculated)

Comment: The aircraft doesn't "need" it. The engineers may _want_ it, but like everything, this is a compromise, and there are workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Putting anything made of metal in front of the radar antenna housing will put a blind spot in the radar's beam. There are plenty of other places on an airframe to obtain useful pitot readings beside the tip of the nose.